# Cannot Open Eclipse Marketplace PKIX path building failed

Tags: eclipse, pkix, eclipse-marketplace

I'm trying to access the Eclipse Marketplace to do a Maven installation on Eclipse IDE however I'm getting this error message. This is the full error message.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3aF7.png)
Sample Code:

```
    org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Cannot install remote marketplace locations: Cannot complete request to https://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.AbstractMarketplaceWizardCommand.createConfiguration(AbstractMarketplaceWizardCommand.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.MarketplaceWizardCommand.createConfiguration(MarketplaceWizardCommand.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.AbstractMarketplaceWizardCommand.execute(AbstractMarketplaceWizardCommand.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:97)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(AbstractContributionItem.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem.lambda$2(AbstractContributionItem.java:475)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4256)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4054)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3642)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:643)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Cannot complete request to https://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.DefaultCatalogService.listCatalogs(DefaultCatalogService.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.AbstractMarketplaceWizardCommand.lambda$0(AbstractMarketplaceWizardCommand.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.transport.httpclient.HttpClientTransport.stream(HttpClientTransport.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.util.FallbackTransportFactory$FallbackTransport.stream(FallbackTransportFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:164)
    ... 5 more
    Suppressed: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Unable to read repository at https://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p.
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.RepositoryTransport.stream(RepositoryTransport.java:191)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingTransport.stream(CachingTransport.java:269)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.util.AbstractP2TransportFactory.invokeStream(AbstractP2TransportFactory.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.util.TransportFactory.lambda$0(TransportFactory.java:421)
        at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.util.FallbackTransportFactory$FallbackTransport.primaryFailed(FallbackTransportFactory.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.util.FallbackTransportFactory$FallbackTransport.stream(FallbackTransportFactory.java:91)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:371)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:314)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:309)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1357)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1232)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1175)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:201)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1505)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1420)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:273)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:241)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:396)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.connectEndpoint(InternalExecRuntime.java:158)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.connectEndpoint(InternalExecRuntime.java:168)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ConnectExec.execute(ConnectExec.java:136)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:175)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpRequestRetryExec.execute(HttpRequestRetryExec.java:96)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ContentCompressionExec.execute(ContentCompressionExec.java:133)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:115)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:170)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:75)
        at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient5.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.performConnect(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1009)
        at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient5.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.access$0(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1001)
        at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient5.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer$1.performFileTransfer(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:997)
        at org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.FileTransferJob.run(FileTransferJob.java:76)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
    Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1341)
        ... 38 more
    Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
        at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
        ... 43 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:371)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:314)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:309)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1357)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1232)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1175)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:201)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1505)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1420)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:273)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:241)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:396)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.connectEndpoint(InternalExecRuntime.java:158)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.connectEndpoint(InternalExecRuntime.java:168)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ConnectExec.execute(ConnectExec.java:136)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:175)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpRequestRetryExec.execute(HttpRequestRetryExec.java:96)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ContentCompressionExec.execute(ContentCompressionExec.java:133)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:115)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:170)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.transport.httpclient.HttpClientService.execute(HttpClientService.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.transport.httpclient.HttpClientService.execute(HttpClientService.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.transport.httpclient.RequestTemplate.execute(RequestTemplate.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.transport.httpclient.HttpClientTransport.stream(HttpClientTransport.java:97)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1341)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
    ... 49 more
Contains: Cannot complete request to https://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.transport.httpclient.HttpClientTransport.stream(HttpClientTransport.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.util.FallbackTransportFactory$FallbackTransport.stream(FallbackTransportFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.RemoteMarketplaceService.processRequest(RemoteMarketplaceService.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.DefaultCatalogService.listCatalogs(DefaultCatalogService.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.AbstractMarketplaceWizardCommand.lambda$0(AbstractMarketplaceWizardCommand.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
    Suppressed: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Unable to read repository at https://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p.
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.RepositoryTransport.stream(RepositoryTransport.java:191)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingTransport.stream(CachingTransport.java:269)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.util.AbstractP2TransportFactory.invokeStream(AbstractP2TransportFactory.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.util.TransportFactory.lambda$0(TransportFactory.java:421)
        at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.util.FallbackTransportFactory$FallbackTransport.primaryFailed(FallbackTransportFactory.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.util.FallbackTransportFactory$FallbackTransport.stream(FallbackTransportFactory.java:91)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:371)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:314)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:309)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1357)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1232)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1175)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:201)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1505)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1420)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:273)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:241)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:396)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.connectEndpoint(InternalExecRuntime.java:158)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.connectEndpoint(InternalExecRuntime.java:168)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ConnectExec.execute(ConnectExec.java:136)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:175)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpRequestRetryExec.execute(HttpRequestRetryExec.java:96)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ContentCompressionExec.execute(ContentCompressionExec.java:133)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:115)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:170)
        at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:75)
        at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient5.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.performConnect(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1009)
        at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient5.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.access$0(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1001)
        at
```

I've tried changing my network connections -> Active Provider from Manual to both Direct and Native like I saw in a similar post however this isn't working. I have also tried dowloading the cert and trying to import it which resulted in a :keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: _.eclipse.org.crt (The system cannot find the file specified) which is untrue because the file is located on my desktop.

Comment: Please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error, hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_.

Comment: Just edited as Sample Code, I couldn't upload the full error message it was too long but this is most of it

Comment: Please show the full error, not only the stack trace (select the error in the _Error Log_ view, do not open it, and hit Ctrl+C).